# How to stop the scroll of particular view at position for RecyclerView android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recycler view.At position 0 ,I had made header and from position 1 rest of the items will come.This is my layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/recyler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@color/listview"
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want when i scroll my recycler view , and when half the header is scrolled up,the remaining header get stick at top ,and other items of recycler view scroll.And after certain point the sticky part of header also moves up.How to achive it.

Comment: I would honestly handle the header view outside of the recycler view if it is going to need to be _that_ dynamic; headers aren't difficult in concept, but getting one to slide in and out half way like this seems like it might be a real challenge.

Comment: how will u handle the header view outside recycler view so that, header scrolls only half up and then sticks.

Comment: You could try doing something like just having the RecyclerView scroll normally, but detecting when the first item is half way out, once it is, have an overlay view that mirrors the first item pushed half way off of the screen. This will give the illusion that the first item has stopped at the top as a header, when in fact it is being scrolled along with the rest of the adapter. Check on scroll down when the first item comes back into view and handle the visibility of the header view. Just off the top of my head, not that that is the _best_ solution.

Comment: As the answer provided below says as well there is the ItemDecorator option, but I don't believe that allows for the ability to scroll, I think that it manages a header that is positioned in a static location at the head of the list.

Answer (score 0):

To make a sticky header you need to provide ItemDecorator to RecyclerView
If You want to do something like [this](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview) .
The library is currently not maintained. You need to make some changes by yourself.

How ItemDecorator works:-
ItemDecorator gives you power to draw something over RecyclerView. In your case you want to put a sticky header for some time and after next header item you want to replace the new header with earlier one.

So Using ItemDecorator you can draw same header view over RecyclerView top position which look like to user as a header item is get fixed on top and when next header item comes it will replace with new one.

Hope It will helps you.